# Как изменить аргумент функции?

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции

Добрый вечер, в JS я новичок и не знаю, возможно ли это сделать.

Есть переменная `adv`, в которой хранится html блок.

Есть функция, в которую в качестве аргумента передаётся эта переменная, и в конце выполнения функции, этой переменной присваивается `false`, чтобы при этой загрузке страницы функция больше не выполнялась.

Однако, при попытке это сделать через аргумент, переменная `adv` не меняет свое значение.

Если в теле функции в лоб прописать `adv = false;` то все в порядке.
Но нужно менять ее через аргумент. Как это можно сделать?

```
var adv = $('#adv');

  function addFalse( id ){
    //выполняемые действия с id...

    id = false;
    console.log( id );// false
    //adv = false;
    console.log( adv );// Object
  }

  addFalse( adv );
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojamKe)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var adv = $('#adv');

  function addFalse(id) {
    //выполняемые действия с id...

    id = false;
    console.log(id); // false
    //adv = false;
    console.log(adv); // Object
    return false;
  }

  adv = addFalse(adv);
})
```

```html
<nav role='navigation' id="adv">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: На англоязычном SO похожую тему поднимали, [хороший ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/556876).

Comment: Sergiks спасибо, заработало)

Comment: Напишите, как заработало. Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, примите его, нажав галочку рядом с ответом.

Comment: Была переменная - обертка jQuery вокруг DOM элемента, стала - булевское значение. Счастливой отладки.

Comment: Теперь заработало как нужно.  Сделал как посоветовал Sergiks .  При вызове функции присваиваю новое значение adv = addFalse(adv); а в конце функции return false и собственно все)  переменная меняет значение как и требовалось.

Comment: 4 Года прошло с момента моих первых шагов в разработке, сейчас просто стыдно за такой вопрос)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, вы можете назначать новое значение при вызове:

```
adv = addFalse(adv);
```

и в функции возвращать `false`.